# Bundler on production server can't find any gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, capistrano, passenger

I am using passenger + nginx to deploy a rails app. The problem I am having is that bundler is not finding any gems when it tries to install them. For instance, I am getting this error:

```
Could not find i18n-0.6.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

If I log onto my production box and manually install the gem, the error goes away, but then the next gem needed cannot be found. Why is this? I am **not** using rvm. Here is my config file:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.0.rc4;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/bin/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  .treadforth.com;
        root /var/www/Tread-Forth/current/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
    }
}
```

Edit: I should add that nginx is running as root. It is possible this is a path issue, but installing the gems manually allows bundle to recognize that they are installed so I am not sure.

Comment: Are you using capistrano? Did you add the `require 'bundler/capistrano'` line to `deploy.rb`?

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem. If you add this an answer I will accept.

Comment: Nice! I'm glad to know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using capistrano, you need to add the line below to `config/deploy.rb`

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
```

Unless you add that, capistrano won't run `bundle install` on the remote server while deploying. It also adds the `--deployment` option that installs all your gems under `shared/bundle`, thereby making a nice separated gem environment for your app.